# Updating a join table record while maintaining counter cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, sqlite

I have a 3-way join table named Listings with the following associations:

```
belongs_to :stage, counter_cache: true, touch: true
belongs_to :list, touch: true
belongs_to :record
```

The List model has many Stages, so the idea of this Listing class is to be able to move a record to different Stages of the List it is in.

However, when I update the listing's stage, it increments the new stage's counter cache and decrements the old stage's counter cache by 2 instead of 1.

E.g.

```
list = List.first
stage1, stage2 = [list.stages.first, list.stages.second] # Assume listing_counts of stage1 and stage2 are 1 and 0, respectively
listing = list.listings.first # Assume that this listing belongs to stage1

# Update the stage of a listing
listing.update(stage: stage2)


stage1.listings_count # Expected: 0, Actual: -1
stage2.listings_count # Expected: 1, Actual: 2
```

Is there some way I can refresh the counter cache? Removing touch: true or trying to do stage.reload didn't work.

Edit:

I've been able to get around this by destroying the listing and readding the record rather than updating the listing directly, but I'd still like to find a way to do it without deleting the listing if possible.

Temporary fix:

```
# Instead of listing.update(stage: stage2)
record = listing.record
listing.destroy
stage2.records << record
```